# is it possible to link cells to a map with basic license smartsheet via API?

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I am working for a charity night now, they are using a smartsheet to store their data. The data contains information of address, what they want is to show points of these data on a map in smartsheet. I can easily convert the data into points using Google Map/Earth to extract the long and lat. However, I am using the basic license that does not support the web content widget. I could also make a html page with all these points showing on the map. This is not the optimal result that I want as the charitys want to integrate the map into Smartsheet, and use smartsheet to have the following functionalities:
- when click on the zip code, there is a pop up window showing the area
- when click on the data point, a window of point located map show pop up

To what I understand, this is not possible with my basic license. And python smartsheet API does not do these (if I can't import map into Smartsheet by logging in, then I can't do this using python either). What I can think of right now to solve the problem is to make a html page and import the link to smartsheet through web content widget.

I wonder if anyone has done something similar with Smartsheet or any suggestions? I think ultimately, no matter what I make (a html, a web application) I would have to integrate it back to smartsheet.

I am still trying to learn what smartsheet can do and am doing tutorials of python API as well as learning so Google Map API for the html page. any feedback would help.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to build functionality into Smartsheet itself. But, if you can use the data in the [sheet](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#get-sheet) with data from the Google Maps API to create a URL of the location you can add that [URL as an attachment to a row](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#attach-url-to-row) in the sheet. Then someone can click that link to go to the page and see the data in Google Maps. You can also add a [hyperlink](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#hyperlinks) to the a cell via the API which could be put into the cell with the zip code by your application.
Your application could create views of HTML with URLs for each of them and as someone visits them it shows them the data based on what is in the sheet.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I think I understand what you mean by that. The charity will be getting a business license so I will be able to use the web content widget. since I do not have the business license myself, I won't be able to test out how Smartsheet data and Google Map API interacts with each other. Do you have any experience inputting Google Map /Google Map API as web content widget to the Smartsheet? does the native Google Map allow you to interact with Smartsheet values? such as that if I click on a values with address, the map will be zoomed/centred to the location?

Comment: You can embed a Google Map in the web content widget in a Dashboard using the embed code provided from Google Maps to highlight a location. The widget doesn't interact with your sheets to pull the location data from a sheet. That will need to be provided to Google Maps via their API and you can then get an embed code to place in the web content widget. Note, the embed code can't be added to the widget via the API. That will have to be done manually via the browser. There aren't available API endpoints to edit widgets in Dashboards.

Comment: Hi and thank you again for your reply. My essential goal is the ability to add points to the map and would like update the new points on a sheet. are you familiar with this? For example, if I geocode values from my google sheet to the map, it will create a lot of points, and I would like to add more points onto the map and get the new points updated to my google sheet as well and Smartsheet. is there a way to do this automatically instead of adding new points to the map then export the new file with new values?

Comment: This sounds possible. I would guess you would have to generate your own page with the HTML for the map and host it at a specific URL. That URL could be added into the web content widget on the dashboard. Then your application could keep the data in Google Sheets and Smartsheet up to date and update the page with the new info. Then the web content widget would show the latest version of the page with the new data.

Comment: once a gain, thank you for your comment and advice. I will try it out!!!!